# jquery nicescroll increasing the width of scrollbar when cursor moves over the scrollbar

Tags: jquery, facebook, scrollbar, nicescroll

I'm using nicescroll plugin. http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

In facebook, the width of the scrollbar is increasing when the cursor moves over the scrollbar. when the cursor moves back, the width of the scroll bar is returning default width. How can we do like this?

Answer (score 4):

Although, this question is very old. But, might be helpful for someone else :

```
jQuery('html').niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",cursorwidth:"8px", boxzoom:true, autohidemode:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the right answer anywhere, so I let myself post my solution:

```css
.nicescroll-cursors {
 -webkit-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
 transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.nicescroll-cursors:hover,
.nicescroll-cursors:active {
 width: 18px !important;
}
```